# POST request is keeping pending,but never gives response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

My MERN project has trouble with backend server. When i look at google chrome's console,the api request is just pending and it's failed after a long while.

server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const connectDB = require('./db');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');


app.use(cors);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes)
connectDB();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port:${port}`));
```

auth.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const { signupValidator, validatorResult } = require('../middleware/validator')
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', signupValidator, validatorResult);

module.exports = router;
```

validator.js

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');
exports.signupValidator = [
    check('username').not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('All fields are requeired'),
    check('email').isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Invalid Email'),
    check('password').isLength({ min: 6 }).withMessage('Password must be at least 6 characters long')
]
exports.validatorResult = (req, res, next) => {
    const result = this.validatorResult(req);
    const hasErrors = !result.isEmpty();
    if (hasErrors) {
        const firstError = result.array()[0].msg;
        return res.status(400).json({
            errorMessage: firstError
        })
        /* console.log('hasErrors:', hasErrors);
        console.log('result:', result);*/
    }
    next();
}
```

request file in frontEnd app:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const signup = async (data) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
    const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/signup', data, config);
    return response;
}
```

I wrote "proxy":"http://localhost:8080" on package.json of backEnd. When i start the server.js,it just shows "Listening on port:8080" on terminal and that's all. How can i take response?

Comment: `this.validatorResult(req);` isn't this will make the call recursive?

Comment: @souravsatyam thanks for your answer. I imported "validationResult" function and edited this part of code as "validationResult(req)". The call is still recursive.

Comment: `exports.validatorResult` change validatorResult method to something else like say `validator` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change server.js

```js
app.use(cors);
```

to

```js
app.use(cors());
```

That will fix responses ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Recursion

The first thing you do when the `validatorResult` function gets called is:

> ```
> const result = this.validatorResult(req);
> ```

… recursively call it. Infinitely. Don't do that.

## No response

Once you fix that,  `validatorResult` will either:

- Return a 400 error *or*
- Use `next()` to hand over to the next piece of middleware or end point

… but there isn't a next piece of middleware or end point.

You have no code which will send a response if there isn't an error.

So it sits there forever.

Comment: I edited my validator.js file. I edited it like this: ```const { check,validationResult } = require('express-validator'); ``` and ```const result = validationResult(req);```. Others remain as same. I make errors and try to send requests. But it is just pending again. How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

`validatorResult()` finishes with `next()`. But there's no more middleware next. The only two are signupValidator, validatorResult... and that's it. So, at the end, you must reply to the browser using `res.end()` or `res.json(....)` or another `res.something` method.